# javascript passing variable in loop

Tags: javascript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have 20 values assigned to a variable StackName. I want to delete all the 20 values one by one passing through a loop. I tried but this but prints all the value at same time.

```
StackName=$(aws cloudformation list-stacks | grep StackName | awk '{FS=" "} {print $2}' | sed "s/\"//g" | sed 's/,//g')

echo "Stack names to be deleted are: ${StackName}" 

for i in ${!StackName[@]} ;

do

  echo "Deleting stack ${StackName}"

    aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name ${StackName}

done
```

Can someone help pls?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Useful place to start is to flag the correct language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aws --query` instead of all that `sed`.

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --query StackSummaries[].StackName --output text
```

It should print all the stack names with spaces in between them which should fit `for` input requirements, so you can do:

```
for stack in `aws cloudformation list-stacks --query StackSummaries[].StackName --output text`; do
  echo "Deleting stack ${stack}"
  aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name ${stack}
done
```

Your original code would probably work too if you use `${i}` in the loop instead of `${StackName}` which contains all the stack names.